# Uploading a large number of files at once

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

how to implement on react uploading a large number of files at a time?

i specified in input multiplu it seems to work but still does not allow to upload more than 1 file at a time

```
const [fileLoad, setLoadFileState] = useState(false);
const [imageState, setImageState] = useState(false);
const [image, setImage] = useState<any>([]);

const refLabel = useRef<HTMLLabelElement>(null);
const openFile = () => refLabel.current?.click();
const uploadFile = () => {}

const changeHandler = async (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    filePromiseAll(event)
    .then((data) =>{
        console.log(data)
    })
}

const filePromiseAll = async (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    
    const filePromise:any = new Promise((resolve) => {
        if(!event.target.files?.length)
            return;
            
        const files = Array.from(event.target.files);
        files.forEach(file => {
            if(!file.type.match('image'))
                return;

            const reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = (ev: ProgressEvent<FileReader>) => {

                if(ev.target)
                    resolve(ev.target.result);
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        })

    })


    return await Promise.all(filePromise);
    
}
```

Comment: You could use https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-file-upload.

Comment: Is it possible to solve this in a standard way?

Comment: Of course it is. See their implementation.